# Reflecting kintone data to Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

Thank you for your help.
I want to access the specified app of kintone from VBA and reflect the data acquired from it in Excel.

"Error number 438 Object does not support this property or method"

And an error is displayed and the value cannot be reflected.
I would appreciate if you could tell me how to solve it.

```
Option Explicit

Const DOMAIN_NAME As String = "XXXXXXXX.cybozu.com"
Const BASE_URL As String = "https://" & DOMAIN_NAME & "/k/v1/" 

Const APP_ID As String = "XXX"
Const API_TOKEN As String = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 

Const cellFromRecNumber = "A2"
Const cellFromRecNumber2 = "B4"

Dim strURL As String 
Dim objHttpReq As Object 

Dim strJSON As String 
Dim objJSON As Object 

Dim strFromRecNumber As String
Dim strToRecNumber As String
Dim strQuery As String

Dim record As Variant
Dim rep As Variant
Dim js As Object
Dim strFunc As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range(cellFromRecNumber)) Is Nothing Then
Exit Sub
Else

Set js = CreateObject("ScriptControl")

js.Language = "JScript"

strFunc = "function jsonParse(s) { return eval('(' + s + ')'); }"

js.AddCode strFunc

strFromRecNumber = Range(cellFromRecNumber)


strQuery = "Userid = """ & strFromRecNumber & """"
strQuery = js.CodeObject.encodeURIComponent(strQuery)

strURL = BASE_URL & "records.json?&app=" & APP_ID & "&query=" & strQuery

Set objHttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

objHttpReq.Open "GET", strURL, False

objHttpReq.setRequestHeader "Host", DOMAIN_NAME & ":443"
objHttpReq.setRequestHeader "X-Cybozu-API-Token", API_TOKEN
objHttpReq.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Thu, 01 Jun 1970 00:00:00 GMT"

objHttpReq.send (Null)

If objHttpReq.Status <> 200 Then
MsgBox ("Send:Error")
End
End If


strJSON = objHttpReq.responseText 
strJSON = Replace(strJSON, """$revision"":", """kintone_revision"":") 

Set objJSON = js.CodeObject.jsonParse(strJSON) 

For Each record In objJSON.records

Worksheets(1).Range(cellFromRecNumber2).Value = record.Officename.Value

Next record

Set objHttpReq = Nothing
Set js = Nothing


End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? 
Also, do you know at which line the error is occurring at?

Comment: Do you have any updates on this? @Beginner